# mapping function keys in vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

I want to map my `F2` for nerdtree with the following entry:

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

But even before that, and after saving the vimrc , whenever i press `F2`, it just switches the case of the letters on which the cursor is present. Later found out that any function key does it. `F5` switches case of 5 characters and so on. Is this because of some other plugin? I presently use c.vim , snippetsEmu , surround , nerdtree , and minibufexpl

There are no keymappings to any function key in my vimrc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your problem is that vim does not know what does terminal emit when you press `<F2>`. On some terminals it emits something like `<Esc>[12~`, so the vim quits current mode (or just beeps if it can't) (`<ESC>`), does nothing (`[1`: there must be some key after `[`, but not 1, so it does nothing) and changes case of two letters (`2~`). So, you should open .vimrc and write there the following:

```
set <F2>=<C-v><F2>
```

where <kbd><C-v><F2></kbd> means that you must press `<C-v>` and then `<F2>`. This line should tell the Vim the exact sequence of codes which is emitted by terminal when you press `<F2>`. After that, use `noremap <F2> whatever` and it should work. If it is not the only terminal that you are using, then you may want to put `if $TERM==#"<C-r>=$TERM<CR>"` before this line and `endif` after.

Comment: oops. I missed the top part last time.it is working now.Thanx.also , wat does noremap do?

Comment: @Mlkhail Like `map`, but prevents using other user mappings. For example, if you have `imap a b` and `imap b c`, then pressing `a` will result in `c`. If you have `inoremap a b` then pressing `a` will result in `b` no matter whether `b` is remapped or not. I recommend never use `?map` unless you do know that you need remapping (for example, with `<Plug>` mappings).

Comment: @Zyx , thanx a lot :) f2 is up and running.

Comment: one more thing.now , i hav set <F2>=(Press)(C-V)<F2>. can i generalise the command for all function keys in one command (using some parameter), or do i hav to give them separately?

Comment: @Mlkhail Only separately. You can automate that using `:while` and `:execute`, but you have to be sure that this is correct. In most of my terminal emulators the result of pressing `<F1>`-`<F4>` is slightly different from the result of pressing `<F5>`-....

Answer (score 10):

```
:map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

After starting Vim you can look with

```
:map <F2>
```

what F2 is mapped to. It is possible that the plugins change the mapping (not visible in .vimrc)

Comment: i tried that.. it says no mapping found.btb, for specifying F2 , u hav to press "F" and "2" right? or do we hav to use ctrl+v?i tried both..still not working.Also I am using SSH Secure Shell Client to login to a FreeBSD server.

Comment: You could try loading vim without any set up

gvim -u NONE -U NONE -N
then in insert mode see what happens when you press the function keys should insert <f2>.
Then Try mapping something simpler to f2 eg
:map   <f2>   "+yy  (yank current line to paste buffer)

Also can you map any function key?

(yes you do type f and 2)

Comment: Also type to see what and where f2 thinks it is set to

:verbose map <f2>

Comment: f2 verbose showed not mappings. and i tried running vim without any setup.f2 is still behaving wierd.mapping something similar is not working either.i do feel it is some problem with my linux machine , since in my home laptop , function key mappings were working fine. i jus dont know how to figure out wat is wrong. :(

Comment: @Mlkhail Have you seen my explanation of this behavior?