# vim: how to map gg=G in insert mode

Tags: vim

Can someone tell me how to map `gg=G` in insert mode. When I use `map <F2> <C-O>gg=G` the cursor is correctly set to the beginning of the file but I then get `=G` inserted. I did try `gg\=G` which also did not work. This is for running MacVim on High Sierra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
inoremap <F2> <ESC>gg=G
```

This creates a non-recursive insertion-mode remapping of `<F2>` to `<ESC>gg=G`. The `<ESC>` is used to move from insert mode into normal mode for `gg=G`.

Note that in order to use function keys as a mapping, you may need to add this additional line to your `.vimrc`, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520904/13172506):

```
set <F2>=<C-v><F2>
```

Comment: You can also use `<C-o>` instead of `<ESC>` to temporarily enter normal mode; after `G` is executed, you'll return to insert mode.

Comment: Okay this is strange, if I use <F2> <C-O>gg<C-O>=G on the command line it works fine. When i setup the mapping in .vimrc it doesn't work.

Comment: @Coltrane58 yeah idk what this answer is trying to do. Your mapping in the comment is the correct solution

Comment: @Coltrane58 Misunderstood your question, sorry. Thought you wanted `gg` to perform `G`. Updating answer..

With regards to your `<F2>` mapping, that issue may be because [your terminal emits something other than <F2> when you hit the F2 key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519532/mapping-function-keys-in-vim).